# не получаю BODY в PUT-запросе (передаю JSON)

Tags: node.js, http, express, postman, put

делаю PUT запрос
[image: отправка PUT из POSTMAN]
и ловлю его в Express

```
app.put('/v1/data/groups/:id', (request, response) => {
console.log('request=>',request)
```

И не могу с ним работать так как в request отсутствует Body, в котором я отправил инфу для изменения объекта.
Что я не так делаю?!

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten)
Я Сделал:

```
    const express = require("express")
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.put('/v1/data/groups/:id', jsonParser, (request, response) => {
    console.log('request=>',request)
```

И получил request.body распарсенным JSON